# How does "that" work in this sentence by Ken Follett?

Tags: relative-clauses, that, dependent-clause, clefts

At the beginning of Ken Follett's book The Pillars of the Earth, he wrote:

"It is in this rich tapestry, where kings and queens are corrupt, that the common man shows eternal promise -- and one majestic creation will bond them forever..."

It looks like "that" means "when" or "while", but I found nothing in dictionaries.

I did find an explanation in Merriam-Webster saying "used as a function word to introduce a subordinate clause modifying an adverb or adverbial expression <will go anywhere that he is invited>", but in the sentence "that" is not modifying an adverb but "tapestry".

Comment: It is an [_**it cleft sentence**_](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/towards-advanced/unit-12/session-1) used for _**emphasis**_

Comment: I am also a reader of Ken Follet., and that book is in my library..but I think this was a style issue to avoid 2 Wh-clauses in the same sentence. Ken Follet is a prolific writer, and some usages might escape someone writing 5000 words a day...

Comment: @fev Thank you! Now that you pointed it out, it becomes very clear to me. If you can kindly add it to the answer, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you as well! I'm not a native speaker. I understand the grammar but sometimes I cannot recognize a structure until someone points it out for me. The big writers like complex sentences. :D

Comment: Use the strategy of meaning preserving transformations to simpler things: "It is in this rich tapestry, where kings and queens are corrupt, that the common man shows eternal promise" -> "It is in this rich tapestry that the common man shows eternal promise" -> "It is here that he shows promise" -> "He shows promise here"

Comment: Keep in my mind that when a "big" writer creates a 'brick' of a book such as Follet's stuff, quite often they are working on a deadline as well as a page minimum...

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for the patient explanation. But I don't get why none of you guys post your answers as actual answers but comments. LOL

Comment: @Cascabel That's fun to know, haha

Comment: Nobody is down-voting...be patient. It' s the weekend...

Comment: I don't post it as an answer because this question will probably be migrated to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Try it!

Comment: I only made it as a comment because I don't consider it an answer. It's a way to help you answer for yourself many questions you might have.